# Is it bad to call write() on a file object frequently with small additions?

Tags: python, performance, file, file-io, stress-testing

I'm refactoring a horrendous python script that is part of the polycode project that generates lua bindings.

I am considering writing lua lines out, as they are generated, in blocks.

But my question in generic form is, **What are the detriments/caveats of writing to a file very quickly?**

Take for example:

```
persistent_file = open('/tmp/demo.txt')

for i in range(1000000):
    persistent_file.write(str(i)*80 + '\n')


for i in range(2000):
    persistent_file.write(str(i)*20 + '\n')


for i in range(1000000):
    persistent_file.write(str(i)*100 + '\n')


persistent_file.close()
```

That's just a simple way to write to a file a lot basically as quickly as possible.
I don't really expect to hit any real problems doing this, but I do want to be informed, is it ever advantageous to cache up for one big write?

Comment: Why should there be any problems? `write()` is just sending data to the file handler in memory, and at certain points determined by the system (unless you call `flush()`) it is written to disk. This may not happen until `close()` is called, it's all done behind the scenes.

Comment: @MattDMo Thank you! I totally knew there had to be, and that I forgot of: a mechanism that did that kind of caching conveniently and automatically for me.

Comment: Same for small reads.  The system will do readahead on the file and cache the data in memory so there is no penalty for small reads or writes.

Comment: …on the other hand you could also write a few lines and profile it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on the `open` function:

> open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None) -> file object
>
> ...
>
> buffering is an optional integer used to set the buffering policy.
>   Pass 0 to switch buffering off (only allowed in binary mode), 1 to select
>   line buffering (only usable in text mode), and an integer > 1 to indicate
>   the size of a fixed-size chunk buffer.  When no buffering argument is
>   given, the default buffering policy works as follows:
>
> - Binary files are buffered in fixed-size chunks; the size of the buffer
>     is chosen using a heuristic trying to determine the underlying device's
>     "block size" and falling back on `io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE`.
>     On many systems, the buffer will typically be 4096 or 8192 bytes long.
> - "Interactive" text files (files for which isatty() returns True)
>     use line buffering.  Other text files use the policy described above
>     for binary files.

In other words, for the most part, the only overhead that you will hit on frequent calls to `write()` is the overhead of a function call.